# $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} ( \frac{p_{2n-1}}{p_{2n}} - \frac{p_{2n}}{p_{2n +1}} ) = ?? $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, prime-numbers, summation-method

Let $ p_n $ be the $n$ th prime.

I was confused about the following idea.

$$A = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} ( \frac{p_{2n-1}}{p_{2n}} - \frac{p_{2n}}{p_{2n +1}} ) $$

Very confused actually.

Does this even converge ? 
Do we need a summability method ?
Does its converge depend strongly on conjectures or theorems about primes ?
Does it value depend strongly on conjectures or theorems about primes ?

Is there a closed form for it ? 
Does its value occur in number theory ?

Does it mimic a random walk ? 
What is the sign of the value ?

How to use analytic number theory for this ?
Or sieve theory ?

Is a zeta-regularized sum possible ?

Cesaro sum or Abel sum ?

*****Motivation*****

I assume it converges because the sums $\sum \frac{ (-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{p_n} $ converge.

But this is apparently very different from zeta functions or prime zeta functions.

Perhaps the gaps between primes are crucial such as the twins. Or maybe arithmetic progressions. 
Or the largest prime gaps like Cramers conjecture or Riemann hypothesis.

Or maybe we can accelerate this infinite sum ?

Comment: Twelve questions asked in one post??  Ask *one* question *well*, first and foremost.  What exactly is your one primary question, and be sure to review [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: the questions are very much related. I think one answer leads to the others. I can post 11 different questions about this but I do not think that would be appreciated. Basicly im asking for more insight. Besides if it Cesarosummable , that would agree with its Abel sum. Making 11 different posts about this feels like spamming imo. @amWhy

Comment: I think your questions, twelve of them, feels like abuse of this site.  How about we compromise, and you divide this question into three to four separate questions, but only first questions first. And only after those first few questions, if you remain clueless, ask the next 3-4 questions.  Likely after asking the first three or four questions, you'll be set to answer the rest on your own.  And if not, then they are not sufficiently related (all 12 questions) to sanction asking them all in one post.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BSum%5Bprime%5B2n-1%5D%2Fprime%5B2n%5D-prime%5B2n%5D%2Fprime%5B2n%2B1%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C1%2C10000%7D%5D%5D) makes it appear that the series converges, but of course the terms are not all positive so maybe there's a problem.  The absolute series for instance has not approached a clear limit by $10^4$ terms, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: Well if a few questions are answered I think I can answer the others. If not , I will accept and make a new question for the remaining. It does not feel like abuse to me since they are so extremely similar. I could say : how to compute this ? Do you need a summability method ? Those are just 2 questions. But that shows little of my thoughts about the situation imho. So I think three questions are rather fragmented into miniquestions.

Comment: Thank you lulu for your helpful comment, I was unaware alpha could do that !

Comment: Thank you Oscar. amWhy seems a strong mathematician with a high rating here. So I assume he does math well. I wonder what the fuss was about for the ban, not to get personal but maybe the question involved interests me. Feel free to link it !!  amWhy seems to have many powers here at MSE , I assume because of high rating. Anyways I respect him and in life we need critics too.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an alternated series, it is obvious that its convergence depends on strong conjectures about primes.

I don't think the strongest conjecture on the prime gap even implies its convergence.

Thus the first step is to check if it converges (almost surely) when replacing $p_n$ by $n\log n$ and $p_{n+1}-p_n$ by (independent) random variables with binomial distribution of parameter $1/\log n$.

Comment: It is not clear which conjectures we need. Or if there is a closed form.